# MySQL return few greatest values from column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I got table with some information about payments. I am taking

```
SELECT id, name, payment FROM Cash;
```

But when i take max(payment) i am getting only one row but i would like to get 3 of higest transaction

Comment: i suggest to add the query you have tryed on your questions, so the answers will be more clear

Answer (score 1):

Use `ORDER BY payment DESC` to get the highest payments first. Then do `LIMIT 3` to get only 3 rows:

```
SELECT id, name, payment
FROM Cash
ORDER BY payment DESC
LIMIT 3
```